# Gitlab Runner Pipeline keeps failing with exit code 1 without any other error message

Tags: docker, gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Hey Folks i'm using currently gitlab inside a Docker image and also an Gitlab Runner inside a Docker image and everything is working fine so far.

I have a build in one stage of the pipeline that is using make to build the project.
There i build an plugin for linux os. This build keeps failing at random positions in the pipeline (i determined it at random because of the line number of the log output) If i open the raw file of the logfile it has nearly similar sizes. See see this log output as example:

```
../src/legacy/PepeBuf.h: In instantiation of ‘PepeBuf<BufferType>::ElementID PepeBuf<BufferType>::findElementID(TimeEx, PepeBuf<BufferType>::ElementID, PepeBuf<BufferType>::ElementID) const [with BufferType = PepeBuf<Spectrum>; PepeBuf<BufferType>::ElementID = BufferElementID]’:
../src/legacy/PepeDoc.h:2032:70:   required from here
../src/legacy/PepeBuf.h:459:69: warning: suggest parentheses around ‘&&’ within ‘||’ [-Wparentheses]
  459 |                    this->_elementIndex == UndefinedBufferElementID  &&  !this->_elementCount);
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/legacy/PepeBuf.h:458:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘ASSERT’
  458 |             ASSERT(this->_elementIndex < this->_numElements  ||
      |             ^~~~~~
../src/legacy/PepeBuf.h: In instantiation of ‘PepeBuf<BufferType>::ElementID PepeBuf<BufferType>::findElementID(TimeEx, PepeBuf<BufferType>::ElementID, PepeBuf<BufferType>::ElementID) const [with BufferType = PepeBuf<EllipseData>; PepeBuf<BufferType>::ElementID = BufferElementID]’:
../src/legacy/PepeDoc.h:2106:70:   required from here
../src/legacy/PepeBuf.h:459:69: warning: suggest parentheses around ‘&&’ within ‘||’ [-Wparentheses]
  459 |                    this->_elementIndex == UndefinedBufferElementID  &&  !this->_elementCount);
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/legacy/PepeBuf.h:458:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘ASSERT’
  458 |             ASSERT(this->_elementIndex < this->_numElements  ||
      |             ^~~~~~
../src/legacy/PepeBuf.h: In instantiation of ‘PepeBuf<BufferType>::ElementID PepeBuf<BufferType>::findElementID(TimeEx, PepeBuf<BufferType>::ElementID, PepeBuf<BufferType>::ElementID) const [with BufferType = PepeBuf<AudioBlock>; PepeBuf<BufferType>::ElementID = BufferElementID]’:
../src/legacy/Pepe.h:2154:67:   required from here
../src/legacy/Pepe.h:459:69: warning: suggest parentheses around ‘&&’ within ‘||’ [-Wparentheses]
  459 |                    this->_elementIndex == UndefinedBufferElementID  &&  !this->_elementCount);
      |                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
../src/legacy/Pepe.h:458:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘ASSERT’
  458 |             ASSERT(this->_elementIndex < this->_numElements  ||
      |             ^~~~~~
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

The Command within the Gitlab Runner keeps failing is `make -j ´nproc´ all`
The same plugin build for windows with this make command in the same docker image is working fine.
Is there any way to get more information about the gitlab runner itself? Why he determined the job as failed?

Gitlab version 15.9.2-ee
Gitlab runner version 15.9.1
docker version 17.06.0-ce, build 02c1d87

I also have an grafana and a prometheus with a node-exporter running and they so not show any problems with the ressources. Any idea where ich can find more informations how and why this jobs failed?

Answer (score 0):

Digging through the systemlogs points me to an OOM Error.

So the solution here was to step back from `make -j ´nproc´ all`  to `make -j 1 all` and this does not fail.
I then increased the number of jobs until the pipeline fails again. I ended up with a `-j 6` to have a sable pipeline build.

Interesting is that the windows build does not have the same problem with out of memory errors.(host, docker image, and pipeline ist exact the same for linux and windows build)